# Android AlarmManager not repeating

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, android-intentservice, android-broadcastreceiver

I have the following problem: I register my alarm manager in `onCreate`, the first time it gets excecuted. But after my delay time (1 min) there should be another execution. But this doesn't work. Why?

My Code:

**AlarmReceiver**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

private AlarmManager mAlarm;
private PendingIntent mAlarmIntent;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, PortalPullService.class);

    String email = Helper.getEmail(context);
    String pw = Helper.getPw(context);
    service.putExtra("email", email);
    service.putExtra("pw", pw);

    startWakefulService(context, service);
}

public void setAlarm(Context context) {
    mAlarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    mAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    int interval = R.integer.update_interval_in_mins * 60 * 1000;

    mAlarm.setInexactRepeating(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            interval,
            interval,
            mAlarmIntent);

    ComponentName reciever = new ComponentName(context, AlarmBootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(reciever,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}

public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    if(mAlarm != null) {
        mAlarm.cancel(mAlarmIntent);
    }

    ComponentName reciever = new ComponentName(context, AlarmBootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(reciever,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
}
```

**PullService**

```
public class PortalPullService extends IntentService {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "PortalPullService";

public PortalPullService() {
    super(LOG_TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


    //TODO make request to ** check if new Infos are available, then send notification
    Helper.sendNotification(this, "Test", "test"); /My test if this works

    AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

}
```

The receiver gets registered via `new AlarmReceiver().setAlarm(this);`

I don't know where is my fault...

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this line:

```
int interval = R.integer.update_interval_in_mins * 60 * 1000;
```

The value for R.integer.update_interval_in_mins is not what you think. It's a constant value assigned during build that points to the integer resource that contains the actual value.

If you want to pull the actual value out of the resource, do this instead:

```
int interval = context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.update_interval_in_mins) * 60 * 1000;
```

Also, you're using [setInexactRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) incorrectly.  Please see that documentation.  You're passing `interval` to it in the place of the time of first alarm (it's not an interval, it's an absolute time).

And don't forget you can log values to see what they are when they're used.

Comment: Thanks, i try this out tomorrow ;)

Comment: Well the first point I understand, I searched for a method directly on the Context `getInteger`, but I didn't found such a method. So I thought this **may** be the correct value. It was pretty stupid not to test it.
For the second point I just used the code they are using in the [Training](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) there they used it the same way as I did ... (referring to ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP examples)
I read the docs, but I thought if they are using it, it should be correct ... P.S. I wrote the code ;)

Comment: That's weird. On that doc page, the example for ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP I think is incorrect.  Later, the example for RTC_WAKEUP is correct.  See how it receives an absolute calendar time.  Bear in mind that the interpretation of the trigger time in millis is based off the clock identified in the first parameter.